# Why does IE11 send 'pragma: no-cache' in request header for ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am testing my web page on IE11. I am making some ajax calls and setting response headers as

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=21600;
```

Though everytime making a request, IE11 sets `Pragma:no-cache` request header. Causing request to get served from origin, though it should have been present in cache.\

Why does IE do that? Is there any way in IE to ignore this header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have tracked this down using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It's a **[red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)**. IE11 only sends the `praga:no-cache` header when the development tools are open.

If you press `F12` and close the development tools you will find that the `no-cache` header is not actually sent on each request. If you just have the development tools open, the `no-cache` header is sent.

You can check it out using fiddler.
Hope it helps...

Comment: Saved me hours :)

Answer (score 10):

You can turn that off when the tools are open by deselecting the circled button:

[image: IE Network Tools]