# Internet Explorer 11 always sends Cache-Control-header during XmlHttpRequest-POST

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

While working on the Internet Explorer-compatibility of our application, I noticed that the `Cache-Control` is always set when performing a `POST` and `OPTIONS` via an XmlHttpRequest. Unfortunately, this is a problem for our storage-provider.

The header is also set when dev-tools is not opened, so this does not seem to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157793/).

I can reproduce this in Internet Explorer 11.0.9600 in a Windows 8 VM.

The following page has an example: https://www.javascripture.com/XMLHttpRequest

Does anyone know why this header is set and possibly how to remove it?

Comment: don't know if you can remove it, but you can possible  override it

Comment: I have not succeeded in removing it. Overriding is possible, but does not solve the issue as the header is still present and has _some_ value.